# Initialize TSQLConnection Driver non-GUI App

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, database-connection

I'm trying to create `TSQLConnection` at run-time on non-GUI application.

```
Uses Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Data.DBXMSSQL; 
...
procedure TFoo.InitializeDB;
begin
  if NOT Assigned(SQLCon) then exit;
  SQLCon.Params.Clear;
  SQLCon.ConnectionName := 'ReportsCon';
  SQLCon.DriverName     := 'MSSQL';
  SQLCon.LoadParamsFromIniFile('C:\ConfigTest\DBTest.ini');
  try
    SQLCon.Connected      := True;
  except
    on E: Exception Do
      LastErr := E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

I got this error

```
DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path.
```

For test purpose i created a new GUI project i dropped `TButton` on the form with the below `OnClick` event

```
Uses Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Data.DBXMSSQL;
...
procedure TForm12.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SQLConnection: TSQLConnection;
begin
  SQLConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    SQLConnection.ConnectionName := 'ReportsCon';
    SQLConnection.DriverName     := 'MSSQL';
    SQLConnection.LoadParamsFromIniFile('C:\ConfigTest\DBTest.ini');
    try
      SQLConnection.Connected      := True;
    except
      on E: Exception Do
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    SQLConnection.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**The code run as expected with no error.**

Both EXE and `dbxmss.dll` are on the same folder

```
C:\Users\$Name\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Win32\Debug
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You might need to call `CoInitialize(nil)` to initialize the COM library at startup, ad finalize with `CoUnInitialize`.

Comment: @kobik Your totally right, Now its working.